# Checking process during vmc push

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am new to Cloud Foundry and have playing around with the micro cloud and also the public Cloud Foundry site. I have one of the sample Sinatra apps to get me started and have successfully deployed this up to cloudfoundry.com. However when I try to deploy the same app to the micro Cloud Foundry instance I get a 'GAVE UP' error.

Does anybody know of any documentation which describes the process of checking an app?

I have looked through the log files on both the public and micro instances and they appear to differ with regards the gems which are being added to the app. I've included them below for reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Craig.

Public log (successful deployment)

```
Reading logs/staging.log... OK
[2013-01-04 12:16:58] Setting up temporary directories
[2013-01-04 12:16:58] Downloading application
[2013-01-04 12:16:58] Unpacking application
[2013-01-04 12:16:58] Staging application
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] # Logfile created on 2013-01-04 12:16:59 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Adding rack-1.4.1.gem to app...
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Adding rack-protection-1.2.0.gem to app...
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Adding tilt-1.3.3.gem to app...
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Adding sinatra-1.3.2.gem to app...
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Adding bundler-1.1.3.gem to app...
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Adding cf-autoconfig-0.0.4.gem to app...
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Adding cf-runtime-0.0.2.gem to app...
[2013-01-04 12:17:00] Creating droplet
[2013-01-04 12:17:01] Uploading droplet
[2013-01-04 12:17:02] Done!
```

Micro log (Failed)

```
Reading logs/staging.log... OK
Logfile created on 2013-01-04 13:46:13 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
Adding cfoundry-0.4.17.gem to app...
Adding clouseau-0.0.2.gem to app...
Adding emk-sinatra-url-for-0.2.1.gem to app...
Adding haml-3.1.7.gem to app...
Adding hashie-1.2.0.gem to app...
Adding interact-0.5.1.gem to app...
Adding json-1.7.6.gem to app...
Adding json_pure-1.6.7.gem to app...
Adding manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.19.gem to app...
Adding mothership-0.3.5.gem to app...
Adding multi_json-1.4.0.gem to app...
Adding multipart-post-1.1.5.gem to app...
Adding rack-1.4.1.gem to app...
```

Comment: have you got a recent Micro Cloud Foundry build?

Comment: Agreed, please make sure you have a recent copy. The more recent releases are a lot more similar to the live environment.

Comment: I have been using a copy included on a micro cloud foundry usb stick so it could well be out of date. I will download the latest version and try that. I will report back to let you know if this resolves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of the micro vm fixed this. Would still be interested to know what the process is when checking an app if anybody knows of any documentation regarding that. Thanks for all the help.
Craig.